# What is a fast way to compare a big list of pairs of integers?

Tags: c, algorithm, list, search, integer

Thing is, we have N pairs of integers, as an example:

> 23 65
>   45 66
>   22 65
>   80 20
>   30 11
>   11 20

We say one pair is bigger than another one if both numbers from one pair are greater than the other two, or if the first number is equal and the other one is bigger, or vice-versa. Otherwise, if you can't compare them that way, then you can't establish which one is bigger.

The idea is to know, for each pair, how many pairs it is bigger to (in the example, the first pair is bigger than the third and the last one, therefore the answer for the first is 2).
The trivial solution would be O(n<sup>2</sup>), which is simply comparing every pair to every other one and adding one to a counter for each positive match.

Can anybody come up with a faster idea?

---

I have implemented the simple solution (N<sup>2</sup>), works reading from "sumos.in":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define forn(i, x, N) for(i=x; i<N; i++)

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("sumos.in");
ofstream fout("sumos.out");

struct sumo{
    int peso, altura;
};

bool operator < (sumo A, sumo B) {
    if( A.altura == B.altura )
        if( A.peso < B.peso )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    else
        if( A.peso == B.peso )
            if( A.altura < B.altura )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        else
            if( (A.altura < B.altura) && (A.peso < B.peso) )
                return true;
            else
                return false;
}

int L;
sumo T[100000];
int C[100000];

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    fin >> L;

    forn(i, 0, L)
        fin >> T[i].peso >> T[i].altura;

    forn(i, 0, L)
        forn(j, 0, L)
            if( j!=i )
                if( T[j]<T[i] )
                    C[i]++;

    forn(i, 0, L)
        fout << C[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Example of input:

```
10 
300 1500
320 1500
299 1580
330 1690
330 1540
339 1500
298 1700
344 1570
276 1678
289 1499
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
1
6
3
3
2
5
0
0
```

---

I solved this problem by using a segment tree. If you wish to see the implementation: http://pastebin.com/Q3AEF1WY

Comment: Seems like it'd be easier to just create an array of pairs and then sort them. That takes O(n) space and O(n log n) to sort. You just need to write the comparison function and call [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). That's the same time complexity as the segment tree, smaller space requirement, and a whole lot less code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution to this but it is rather complex. The basic idea is that there are these groups where the pairs can be arranged in dominated order for example:

```
11 20    30 11
22 65    80 20
23 65
45 65
```

If you start thinking about taking your pairs and trying to create these groupings you realize you will end up with a tree structure. For example imagine we added the pair 81 19 to the list and add a pair (-∞, -∞)

```
     (-∞, -∞)   
    /      \ 
11 20      30 11 ---\
22 65      80 20    81 19
23 65
45 65
```

If you follow the path from a node to the root you will count how many pairs the current pair dominates. From this example it kind of looks like you can use binary search to figure out where to insert a pair into the structure. This is where the complexity troubles start. You can't do a binary search/insertion on a linked list. However there is a very neat data structure called a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) you might use. You can basically search and insert in O(logn) time.

There's still one problem. What if there are tons of these groupings? Imagine a list like

```
11 20
12 19 
13 18
14 17
```

You're tree structure will look like:

```
           (-∞, -∞) 
    /      /       \      \ 
11 20    12 19   13 18   14 17
```

Again use skip lists to order these nodes. I think this will require two different kinds of nodes in the tree, a horizontal type like above and a vertical type like in the first examples. When you are done constructing the tree, do a iterate the tree with DFS while recording the current depth to associate each pair with the number of nodes it dominates.

If the above algorithm is correct you could insert a the pair into the tree in O(logn) time and thus all the pairs in O(nlogn) time. The DFS part will take O(n) time thus constructing the tree and associating a pair with the number it dominates will take O(nlogn) time. You can sort the pairs based on the number of dominations in O(nlogn) time so the whole process will take O(nlogn) time.

Again there is probably a simpler way to do this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The amount of pairs is of about 100.000, so i expected N log N time. I will try what you say

Comment: I solved this problem by using a segment tree, it works in O(N log N)

If you wish to see the implementation: http://pastebin.com/Q3AEF1WY

Answer (score -1):

You can use. A sort. like this

```
int z = {23,65,45, 66,22,65,80,20,30,11,11, 20};
```

int i, j, k, tmp;

```
for (i=1; i<n; i++){
    j= n-i-1;

    for (k=0; k<=j; k++)
```

//Put attention on this block.

```
        if (z[k]>z[k+1]){
            tmp= z[k];
            z[k]= z[k+1];
            z[k+1]= tmp;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what i am asking here